# next-auth and django rest framework - how should I fetch user data after JWT authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, next.js, next-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm building an app that uses the Django rest framework and simplejwt to authorize the users.

I'm having trouble understanding what should be the optimal way of fetching user data after the user logs in and JWT is provided.

Let's say I'd want to display the user name and email on the navigation bar. Should I:
a) add the user name and email to the JWT response (not encoded)?
b) after getting the JWT, use it to fetch the user data?

As of now, my JWT (/api/auth/) endpoint response looks something like this:

```
{
  "refresh": "refresh_token",
  "access": "access_token"
}
```

And here's an example of the decoded access token:

[decoded access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrq8u.png)

I thought that perhaps the next-auth decodes the JWT response and pulls the user data from there.